# How do I execute a photoshop droplet from the command line on mac osx?

Tags: ruby, macos, photoshop

Added: The problem: the script runs and photoshop opens, but the droplet doesn't execute on the jpg file to watermark it.

Original:
I'm automating a work flow using ruby on mac osx. The aim being to pass my ruby script a directory (containing images), it opens each one, checks the orientation & size, and passes the image to the relevant photoshop droplet based on this, then uploads them to flickr.

Initially I was using 'system' to try and run the droplet because I thought it was an executable binary.

Of course the droplet requires photoshop to run it so instead I've tried this:

```
system('open /Users/fullpath/watermark_landscape_W600 --args /Users/fullpath/y020_Pork_Terrine_Orange_Paste_Bread.JPG')
```

LaunchServices is clearly returning the correct application because photoshop opens.

I enabled history logging in photoshop in the vain hope that it would tell me what droplets and parameters were passed to photoshop when it was opened but the output is very poor:

```
2013-07-14 12:45:53 Photoshop launched
2013-07-14 12:47:06 Photoshop quit
```

How can I check to see that open is passing the correct parameters to osx and photoshop? is there a stand error log output I can hook into?

Comment: You sort of forgot to say what the actual problem? What did or didn't happen that you expect to (not) happen?

Comment: Traditional OS X apps don't use the argv style arguments at all, when invoking launch services directly you specify the document to open by creating an appleevent and including that as one of the launch parameters. No idea how you do that with `open` though, although you might try opening the image and using -a to specify the droplet

Answer (score 3):

I've been able to use Photoshop 2022 droplets by calling them within the package.

```
./YourDroplet.app/Contents/MacOS/Droplet /full/path/to/file.jpg
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer: Opens photoshop and executes the droplet on the image:
NOTE: '--args' omitted:

```
open -a /full_path/watermark_foodlab_landscape_W600 /full_path/y020_Pork_Terrine_Orange_Paste_Bread.JPG
```

Thanks Frederick that worked a treat!!

Combinations tried:

Opens photoshop:

```
open /full_path/watermark_foodlab_landscape_W600
```

Opens photoshop and opens image in preview:

```
open /full_path/watermark_foodlab_landscape_W600 /full_path/y020_Pork_Terrine_Orange_Paste_Bread.JPG
```

Opens photoshop:

```
open -a /full_path/watermark_foodlab_landscape_W600 --args /full_path/y020_Pork_Terrine_Orange_Paste_Bread.JPG
```

Opens photoshop and opens image in preview:

```
open ./watermark_foodlab_landscape_W600 ./y020_Pork_Terrine_Orange_Paste_Bread.JPG
```

Opens photoshop:

```
open ./watermark_foodlab_landscape_W600 --args ./y020_Pork_Terrine_Orange_Paste_Bread.JPG
```

Unable to find application named './watermark_foodlab_landscape_W600'

```
open -a ./watermark_foodlab_landscape_W600 ./y020_Pork_Terrine_Orange_Paste_Bread.JPG
```

Quick rain dance . . .

NOTE: '--args' omitted:
Opens photoshop and executes the droplet on the image:

```
open -a /full_path/watermark_foodlab_landscape_W600 /full_path/y020_Pork_Terrine_Orange_Paste_Bread.JPG
```

Re-reading the man page this makes sense, but I certainly didn't interpret it that way!!!
Right of to sit in the sun and bask in glory with a pint! (it is sunday after all)